# htaccess redirect with php variables ...

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using this format in my htaccess to redirect several pages/links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule special.php http://www.mysite.com [R=301]
...
...
RewriteRule http://www.mysite.com/special.php?t=master http://www.mysite.com/index.php?q=former [R=301, L]
```

I noticed, first, that only the top line is catching anything, and in fact the others, like the bottom line, did nothing until I put in that top line. Any ideas why?

Second, mysite.com/special.php?t=grave is redirected, by the above top line, to mysite.com/?t=grave , thus retaining the variables in the URL. I don't want this, I simply want it to go to mysite.com with no variables. How do I do this?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: top line, as in 'rewriteengine on'? Typically a room stays dark until you turn on the lights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your first rule catches **any** URI with `special.php` in it, even if it is followed by a bunch of characters. To limit it to only and exactly `special.php`, and to make sure the query string is discarded, change it to

```
RewriteRule ^special.php$ http://www.mysite.com/? [L, R=301]
```

Secondly, rewrite rules only match the part **after** http://www.mysite.com/ (note the last slash) and **before** the query string (the part after the question mark). So if you change the format of those rules to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=master
RewriteRule ^special.php$ index.php?q=former [R=301, L]
```

you should be good to go.